# Trouble with Select Distinct and Union

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum age range counts from two tables.  I was able to get the totals from both tables to show into one view, but can not figure out how to get evac center duplicates out and have all totals on one row for each evac center.

When I add a Select Distinct to each table I get errors.

```
SELECT dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.EvacCenter AS [Evac Center], SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.Age < 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5 and Under], 
                         SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.Age BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6 to 17], 
             SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.Age > 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18 and Over]
FROM  dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV
WHERE        (dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.CheckedIn = 1)
Group by dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.EvacCenter
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.EvacCenter AS [Evac Center], SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.Age < 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5 and Under], 
                         SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.Age BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6 to 17], 
             SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.Age > 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18 and Over]
FROM dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV
Group by dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.EvacCenter
```

Comment: Perhaps the [Database Administrators.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for a question like this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you want.

First combine your two SELECTs like this. Note that we use UNION instead of UNION ALL to match your first part of the question *to get evac center duplicates out*.

```
SELECT dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.EvacCenter AS [Evac Center], 
       dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.Age
FROM   dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV
WHERE  (dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.CheckedIn = 1)
UNION
SELECT dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.EvacCenter AS [Evac Center], 
       dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.Age
FROM   dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV
```

Now make your SUMs using

```
SELECT EvacCenter AS [Evac Center], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Age < 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5 and Under], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6 to 17], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Age > 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18 and Over]
FROM (
   SELECT dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.EvacCenter as EvacCenter, 
          dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.Age as Age
   FROM   dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV
   WHERE  (dbo.tblGenPopRegistration_DEV.CheckedIn = 1)
   UNION
   SELECT dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.EvacCenter as EvacCenter, 
          dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV.Age as Age
   FROM   dbo.tblGenPopAdditionalRegistrations_DEV
) GROUP BY EvacCenter
```

The second part of your question is to *have all totals on one row for each evac center.*
I don't know if we have this result already.

If not, please provide an example and mention your SQL database or SQL dialect.
I suppose you want a result you can get by using the keywords

```
OVER PARTITION BY
```

Comment: I'm lost.  How do I combine part 2 with part 1.  The steps in part 1 return 9 rows  (EvacCenter and Age) columns, but I'm still confused as to how I can get the sums for the age ranges.

Comment: @Tammi My first block is already in the second block. No need to combine it.
How about providing an example result table by editing your question and showing how you want the data result to look like.